# How to build a grid with 5 cols and 10 rows

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a grid with 5 cols and 10 rows and in each column the values should be 0-9 on click on the any number I have
to get the value of the clicked cell. what is the best way to build this ?

[image]

Comment: What does each row represent?

Comment: it should have 0-9 in each column from (1,0)to (10,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, and without knowing more about the requirements it's hard to say which one would be best.

One way could be to attach a mouse click listener to the Grid, and in the handler, calculate which cell was clicked.

```
Grid grid = e.Source as Grid;
Point clickedPoint = e.GetPosition(Grid.RowProperty);
int rowClicked = (int)Math.Floor(clickedPoint.Y / grid.RowDefinitions.Count);
```

This is good for performance as there's only one event listener -- but you'd have to make sure that any elements you place on top of the Grid allow click events to bubble up (that is, if they implement a click listener, they should use `e.Handled = false`).

---

Another way, if you have UI elements in the Grid cells, would be to attach a click listener to each element in the Grid, and use `clickedElement.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty)` to get the row number.

---

**Edit** You could create a simple 5x10 grid using code-behind like this:

```
        const int columns=5, rows=10;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                if (i==0) grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                var content = new TextBlock() { Text = j.ToString() };
                Grid.SetColumn(content, i);
                Grid.SetRow(content, j);
                grid.Children.Add(content);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I added the image how the grid should look like, how to do this ?

Comment: @Gani sorry, I can't see the image right now (IT at work blocks it).  I'll have to take a look later.

Comment: @Kumar please see my update.  Note that this question is really too general to be a good fit for Stack Overflow -- normally questions are expected to have tried something first, and to ask something specific.